# Most efficient way to parse a string Groovy?

Tags: groovy

What is the most efficient way to parse the following string in Groovy?

```
 slt-5.16.1.0XYZ
```

So that I obtain the following result:

```
 slt-5.16
```

The values 5 and 16 can be 1-nnn.

Help always appreciated.

Comment: Hi Peter, please accept Giuseppe Ricupero's answer, I'm going to remove mine once he edits it to show proper benchmarking 

Comment: @tim_yates: very kind of you, thank you. For me it was sufficient to discover `gbench` :)

Answer (score 3):

I would have suggested to use a simple `regex` in this context but since you have asked for the most efficient way I've tried several approaches.

**TL;DR**

Use `substring()` and a couple of nested `indexOf()`:

```
input.substring(0, input.indexOf('.', input.indexOf('.') + 1 ) )
```

**Long Story (updated)**

I've updated the benchmarks using the nice suggestion of **Tim Yates** also adding some interesting variations. Following you can find the results, some considerations and the code used to produce them:

```
Environment
===========
* Groovy: 2.4.14
* JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.71-b00, Oracle Corporation)
    * JRE: 1.8.0-internal
    * Total Memory: 117 MB
    * Maximum Memory: 1710.5 MB
* OS: Linux (4.13.0-37-generic, amd64)

Options
=======
* Warm Up: Auto (- 60 sec)
* CPU Time Measurement: On

                                               user  system    cpu   real

indexOf                                         329       0    329    330
regex, just not a dot                           704       7    711    722
manual loop, int vars                           885       0    885    896
tokenizeJoin                                   1074       0   1074   1079
manual loop, int vars and def i                1078       0   1078   1090
manual loop, Integer vars                      1065       3   1068   1085
manual loop, def vars                          1122       0   1122   1127
regex, restricting to number                   2725      24   2749   2760
manual loop, int vars but index without type  33087       0  33087  33132
manual loop, without types                    47600     286  47886  47944
```

Some short considerations:

- regex with negated group is faster (actually the second one in ranking) than the one restricting to group (4 times slower)
- the manual loop is fast as I was expecting if you use the static types: `int` is the fastest one. `Integer` is slower and comparable to `def`. Leaving them without any type is the slowest solution!

The code:

```
@Grab('org.gperfutils:gbench:0.4.3-groovy-2.4')

def input  = 'slt-5.16.1.0XYZ'
def target = 'slt-5.16'

benchmark {
    'indexOf' {
        assert target == input.substring(0,
                           input.indexOf('.', input.indexOf('.') + 1)
                         )
    }
    'regex, just not a dot' {
        assert input.find(/^[^.]+[.][^.]+/) == target
    }
    'manual loop, int vars' {
        int index, counter = 0 
        for (int i=0; i <input.size(); i++) {
            if (input[i] == '.') { counter++ }
            if (counter == 2) { index = i; break }
        }
        assert input.substring(0,index) == target
    }
    'tokenizeJoin' {
        assert input.tokenize('.').take(2).join('.') == target
    }
    'manual loop, int vars and def i' {
        int index, counter = 0 
        for (def i=0; i <input.size(); i++) {
            if (input[i] == '.') { counter++ }
            if (counter == 2) { index = i; break }
        }
        assert input.substring(0,index) == target
    }
    'manual loop, Integer vars' {
        Integer index, counter = 0 
        for (Integer i=0; i <input.size(); i++) {
            if (input[i] == '.') { counter++ }
            if (counter == 2) { index = i; break }
        }
        assert input.substring(0,index) == target
    }
    'manual loop, def vars' {
        def index, counter = 0
        for (def i=0; i <input.size(); i++) {
            if (input[i] == '.') { counter++ }
            if (counter == 2) { index = i; break }
        }
        assert input.substring(0,index) == target
    }
    'regex, restricting to numbers' {
        assert (input =~ /(.+-\d+\.\d+)/)[0][1] == target 
    }
    'manual loop, int vars but index without type' {
        int index, counter = 0 
        for (i=0; i <input.size(); i++) {
            if (input[i] == '.') { counter++ }
            if (counter == 2) { index = i; break }
        }
        assert input.substring(0,index) == target
    }
    'manual loop, without types' {
        counter = 0
        for (i=0; i <input.size(); i++) {
            if (input[i] == '.') { counter++ }
            if (counter == 2) { index = i; break }
        }
        assert input.substring(0,index) == target
    }
}.prettyPrint()
```

Comment: Very interesting! I would have thought the regex method would have been the most efficient. I think I'll use the most readable. Just looking to impress my "friends".